# how to use hmm for classification using HMM matlab Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, classification, hidden-markov-models

I'm using the hidden Markov model for classification.
first, I divided the dataset into two categories:  training dataset and test dataset.
I'm using this [tollbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html?w.mathworks.com).

I did the training using hmmtrain.
But I don't know what function to use for classification?
Should I use hmmdecode or hmmviterbi or... ? And how should I do classification?

I couldn't find any examples on the internet.

I would be very grateful for your kind help.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple answer to 'how do I use a hidden Markov model for classification', so there isn't a simple answer to 'how do I use a hidden Markov model for classification in MATLAB'. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91290/how-do-i-train-hmms-for-classification) for example. I think at this stage you have a stats question rather than a programming question.

Comment: Do you have a specific data set? If so, would you please share it for us to try?